# Password Rotation of Administrator account in windows VM

Tags: azure-functions

I wanted to automatically change password of my administrator account in windows vm in azure. I have multiple vm's present in my account, and password of administrator account of each vm should change after 30 days and should be saved in keyvault. can anyone help me with this please..

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: i tried using azure functions, but it didnt worked out properly..

Comment: So basically , you want to change your Azure VM admin password and save the new password value in key vault ? Is the new password will be  created by your own rule? Will you consider using Azure automation to do it ?

Comment: yes, i will consider azure automation to do it

Answer (score 1):

If you will consider using [Azure automation powershell runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook) to do it, try the PowerShell below to update new password for your windows VMs and save the new password into key vault :

```
$username = "<your Azure account>"
$passwd = "<your Azure account password>"
$keyVaultName = "<your key vault name>"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpasswd)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -TenantId "<your tenant ID>" -SubscriptionId "<your subscription ID>"

#define new password 
$admin = "mgr" 
$adminPasswd = "password1234!"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $adminPasswd -AsPlainText -Force
$newCred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($admin, $secpasswd)

#get all windows azure vms and set new password 
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM | Where-Object {$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq "Windows"}
foreach($vm in $VMs){
    Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -VMName $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName  -Name "enablevmaccess" -Credential $newCred 
}

#save new password into key vault 
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName  $keyVaultName -SecretValue $secpasswd -Name "NewPassword"
```

If you need to do this process every 30 days , just [create a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules#creating-a-schedule) after you publish your run book.

Pls note, before you run the powershell command, you should know 2 things :
1.import ps models below in gellary first :
[image]
Import this two modules step by step :

[image]
It will take some time to import it .
[image]

Once the two modules all are available , its done :
[image]

2. Make sure the account that you used for login has the permission to add secrets into your key vault. If it has no permission to do it , [follow this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-group-permissions-for-apps) to map access policy in your key vault:
   [image]

Result :
After I run this ps runbbok, my vm password has been updated and a new secret has been created in key vault :
[image]

Hope it helps .